# Get description of groups from within a grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to write a function that will take in a grouped data frame (from dplyr) and make a plot for each group, with the title describing what group it is for. The kicker is I don't know what the grouping variable is, or even how many there will be.

I've hacked together something using `groups` to get the grouping variables and then accessing the value with `.[1,g]`, where `g` is a character version of the grouping variable names, as below.

Although I'm new to dplyr, this feels like the wrong way to go about this, that is, it's not really a dplyr native way of doing it. It works in the little testing I've done but I'm worried it will fail in some odd circumstance I haven't foreseen. How would you all do it? Is there a more `dplyr`-ish way of doing it?

On the odd chance that what I've done is actually a good idea, I've posted it as answer for you all to vote on as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d) # or create directly as data.table

par(mfrow = c(2, 3))

d[, plot(y, main = paste(names(.BY), .BY, sep = "=", collapse = ", ")), by = .(A, B)]
```

[image]

Comment: So if someone passes me a grouped data frame, how do I use those groups in the by?

Comment: Tell someone to stop wasting time passing you "grouped" data frames. But if they don't care and insist on doing it, use `by=c(as.character(groups(their_grouped_data.frame)))`

Comment: Not a big fan of the new dplyr stuff, eh?

Comment: Correct. But my personal tastes aside, it is simply not up to the task for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've hacked together; as described in the question, it uses `groups` to get the grouping variables and then accessing the value with `.[1,g]`, where `g` is a character version of the grouping variable names, as below.

Instead of making a plot, it just makes a data frame with the title as a variable.

```
library(dplyr)
d <- as.tbl(data.frame(expand.grid(A=1:3,B=1:2,y=1:2)))

d1 <- d %>% group_by(A)
g <- unlist(lapply(groups(d1), paste))
d1 %>% do(data.frame(title=paste(paste(g, "=", .[1,g]), collapse=", "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
## Groups: A [3]
##  
##       A title
##   <int> <chr>
## 1     1 A = 1
## 2     2 A = 2
## 3     3 A = 3

d1 <- d %>% group_by(A, B)
g <- unlist(lapply(groups(d1), paste))
d1 %>% do(data.frame(title=paste(paste(g, "=", .[1,g]), collapse=", "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## Groups: A, B [6]
##  
##       A     B        title
##   <int> <int>        <chr>
## 1     1     1 A = 1, B = 1
## 2     1     2 A = 1, B = 2
## 3     2     1 A = 2, B = 1
## 4     2     2 A = 2, B = 2
## 5     3     1 A = 3, B = 1
## 6     3     2 A = 3, B = 2
```